# .NET Configurable interface implementation

Tags: .net, interface, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have an interface and I wish to do a factory pattern to instantiate different implementor of the interface. But I wish to keel the details of which implementor to be instantiated in the config file. I shall like to have it in the fashion of RoleProvider configuration:

```
<section name="MembershipProvider" type="MyOwn.UserManagement.Providers.MembershipProvider.CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection,MyOwn.UserManagement.Providers.MembershipProvider" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
```

So its kind of an dependency injection technique. Can somebody help me?

Edit:

The actual situation is like this:

I have an interface `IDataExchange` and want to implement it with different assemblies for different customers. So I might have two assemblies that have classes implementing `IDataExchange` say, `DataExchange1` and `DataExchange2`. Now when I deploy, depending upon to which customer I am providing it, I shall like to set the details of the assembly (either `DataExchange1` or `DataExchange2`) in the config file. This will also allow me or any developer to write new assemblies implementing  `IDataExchange` for any change required, if the instantiation decision is handled automatically.

So how can I do it?

**My implementation:**

Thanks to all of you. And special thanks to *@Pauli Østerø*

I have taken cue from your answers and implemented a solution.

In the config file I added the following:

```
<add key="Exchanger" value="DExchanger.DExchange1, DExchanger.DExchange1"/>
```

I added a class (to work as a DI container or the abstract factory). The class is `DIContainer` containing the following method:

```
public IDataExchange CreateInstance(string config)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(config);
    return (IDataExchange)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

And while I am instantiating, I write the following:

```
    var config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Exchanger");
    DIContainer x = new DIContainer();
    var instance = x.CreateInstance(config);

    Console.Write("Provide your input please: ");
    string inp=Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(instance.DoDataExchange(inp));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

And this is giving me the result I was looking for.

I shall request all of you to put your feedback for further improvement.

Comment: what are you exactly asking for? now you have defined the section and a type to handle it. depending on what group your section is defined in you would need to add actual configuration data further down in your config file.

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: Edited my post to clarify what I wished to know.

Comment: @Pauli Østerø:Is my implementation something near to a DI?

Comment: i wouldn't say its DI but more like IOC... without being a master in the terms, i would say DI covers areas like *if the constructor takes this paramater, then automatically pass an instance of the right type* while simple IOC is seperating the concerns of how to instantiate concrete implementations of a interface, which is what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have some requirements for the things that I wrote. And I wish to learn DI now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your `CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection` named `Type` so you can configure it like this in your config file

```
<group>
   <MembershipProvider type="... my concrete type" />
</group>
```

On your `CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection` you create a method named `CreateInstance` that returns `IDataExchange`. The body of the method is pretty simple

```
public IDataExchange CreateInstance()
{
   var type = Type.GetType(this.Type);
   return (IDataExchange)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

and when you need an `IDataExchange` reference you write

```
var config = (CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("group/MembershipProvider");
var instance = config.CreateInstance();
```

Comment: I could not understand how I can create the CreateInstance method in CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: CustomMembershipProviderConfigurationSection is a class... a normal .net class where you can write normal methods in.

Answer (score 1):

Most **Dependency Injection Containers** will be able to do what you ask for through their support for **XML configuration**.

Some common DI Containers are:

- [Castle Windsor](http://castleproject.org/container/index.html)
- [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm)
- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)
- [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at MEF.
[Clickity click](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

It should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: MEF has no built-in support for XML configuration.